# Finding the maximum value of the following equation

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

For $N\in \mathbb{N}$, $M\in \mathbb{N}$, and $K\in \mathbb{N}$, $f(K)$ is given by
\begin{equation}
f(K) = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{K} {\left( {\frac{{\left( {M - K} \right)!\left( {M - i} \right)!}}{{\left( {M - i - K} \right)!M!}}} \right)^{N - 1}  \cdot \left( \begin{array}{c}
 K \\ 
 i \\ 
 \end{array} \right) \cdot \left( { - 1} \right)^{i - 1} } 
\end{equation},
where $M\ge K$.

We found that $f(K)$ is a convex function by plotting $f(K)$ for varying $K$. 
We would like to solve the above equation as a closed-form.
Does anyone help us for solving it or suggesting any ideas?

Comment: I think it would help if we had some context as to where this equation came from. Also, why you are convinced there is a nice closed form.

Comment: Also, what maximum value do we have to find?